# Prove that $(a^m)^n=a^{m \cdot n}$ for all $n$ and $m$ in $\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was doing an algebra problem and I got stuck. Here is the proposition and what I have done. Any clue to continue? Thanks in advance!

**DEFINITION:** $z^n=|z|^n$ if $n$ is even or $z\geq 0$
; $z^n=-|z|^n$ if $n$ is odd and $z<0$.

***Prove that $(a^m)^n=a^{m \cdot n}$ for all $n$ and $m$ in $\mathbb{N}$.***

Let $a$ be an arbitrary integer and $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$. We have 4 cases:

**Case 1:** $m$ and $n$ are even or $a\geq 0$.

Since $m$ and $n$ are even or $a \geq 0$, it follows from the definition of absolute value that $a^m=|a|^m$ and that $m \cdot n$ is even, so $a^{m \cdot n}=|a|^{m \cdot n}$. Thus,

$(a^m)^n = (|a|^m)^n = |a|^{m \cdot n} = a^{m \cdot n}$

**Case 2:** $m$ and $n$ are odd and $a < 0$.

Since $m$ and $n$ are odd and $a < 0$, it follows from the definition of absolute value that $a^m=-|a|^m$ and that $m \cdot n$ is odd, so $a^{m \cdot n}=-|a|^{m\cdot n}$. Thus,

$(a^m)^n = -|-|a|^m|^n = -(|a|^m)^n = (-1) \cdot (|a|^m)^n = (-1) \cdot (|a|^{m \cdot n}) = -|a|^{m\cdot n} = a^{m \cdot n}$

**Case 3:** $m$ is even, $n$ is odd, and $a<0$.

Since $m$ is even, $n$ is odd and $a<0$, it follows from the definition of absolute value that $a^m=|a|^m$ and that $m \cdot n $ is even, so $a^{m \cdot n}=|a|^{m \cdot n}$. Thus,

$(a^m)^n = -|a^m|^n =$ **AND HERE IS WHERE I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO, I'm pretty sure that my mistake is how i am operating the absolute value.**

**Case 4:** $m$ is odd, $n$ is even, and $a<0$.

Since $m$ is even, $n$ is odd and $a<0$, it follows from the definition of absolute value that $a^n=-|a|^n$ and that $m \cdot n$ is even, so $a^{m \cdot n}=|a|^{m \cdot n}$. Thus,

$(a^m)^n = |-|a|^m|^n = (|a|^m)^n = |a|^{m \cdot n} = a^{m \cdot n}$

Comment: You really don't need to work with moduli here, let alone cases. Just induct on $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately my professor told us to do it exclusively by cases.

Comment: What a strange requirement; thanks for explaining it. Anyway,  you've somehow picked up a $-$ sign in one case, when you tried to reason$$(a^m)^n=(|a|^m)^n=|a|^{mn}=a^{mn}.$$You should be able to fix it if you double-check the parity of each exponent.

Comment: @J.G. says "*induct on* n".  Or consider that visually the claim is obvious: `a^m` is a row of `m` `a`s, and `(a^m)^n` is `n` of those rows, making `n × m` `a`s to be multiplied together.
Is there a strict proof of the claim using this simple method?

Comment: Even more fun: Show that all the exponent rules hold for rationals $(a^p)^q=a^{pq},\,a^p\cdot a^q=a^{p+q}$, etc., and then try to show that it holds for rational sequences : ) That once took me a while

Comment: But as J.G. says, doing this by induction is the most natural and really the only sensible way to go (or just by obvious inspection as Ray comments)